# Trying to get my GUI windows automatically exit when I open the next window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

How can I manage to automatic cancel this 1st window when I click the next window button?

sample code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
root.title("GUI practice")

def open():
    top = Toplevel()  # new window
    top.title("Kokomi")
    labels = Label(top, text="This one automatically close when i click the next window").pack()
    button2 = Button(top,text="Close window", command=top.destroy).pack()
    button3 = Button(top,text="Next window", command=open2).pack()

def open2():
    top = Toplevel()  # new window
    top.title("Guide")
    labels = Label(top, text="end").pack()
    button2 = Button(top, text="Close window", command=top.destroy).pack()  # destroy to quit things

button = Button(root, text="Open(No need to close this)", command=open).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

---

```
[Click open][1]
[Click Next window and after that this windows should disappear and continue to the 3rd picture][2]
[The 2nd picture goes disappear when i click the next window][3]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/plS1T.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFW76.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSZCp.png
```

Comment: Do you need two `open` functions?

Comment: yes sir... im trying to make the other one disappear when i click the next window.. but two command  doesn't work

Comment: I feel like there is some more issues here, can you make your objectives more clear. Why are you opening two windows

Comment: I am trying to make a map locator GUI, a project of mine in college.. I need multiple windows like around 15..

Comment: So are you going to make 15 functions? I can give you an answer for this 2 functions, but if the number of functions are going to increase, then you might need a better solution, which is why I asked you to explain your case better. Are these 15 windows going to be similar? or some pattern in these windows

Comment: The only similar im going to make is the next window and the close window... I'm sorry i'm quite new to this.. i can't really explain it well... I don't know if sending pictures here is okay.. I can explain it well by pictures

Comment: Yes you can use pictures

Comment: [Click open][1]
[Click Next window and after that this windows should disappear and continue to the 3rd picture][2]
[The 2nd picture goes disappear when i click the next window][3]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/plS1T.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFW76.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSZCp.png

Comment: @KurtLee dont use names like `open` that are already reserved for built-in operations. You will overwrite these names and might lose functionality that you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

For this specific case of using two functions and two windows, you can just simply rename the `Toplevel` widgets to different names and then globalize one and then access it from another function and destroy it before the new windows is shown.

```
def open():
    global top
    top = Toplevel()  # new window
    top.title("Kokomi")

    Label(top, text="This one automatically close when i click the next window").pack()
    Button(top, text="Close window", command=top.destroy).pack()
    Button(top, text="Next window", command=open2).pack()

def open2():
    top.destroy() # Destroy previously open window
    top1 = Toplevel()  # new window
    top1.title("Guide")

    Label(top1, text="end").pack()
    Button(top1, text="Close window", command=top1.destroy).pack()  # destroy to quit things
```

If you noticed, I removed the variable names of buttons and labels because its useless to have those as their value is `None`, read [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1101750/13382000).

When you wish to use more functions and windows, you have to manually follow this procedure for all the functions. Unless ofcourse there is a better and cleaner way of designing your app using classes and frames.

**Alternatively** you can also invoke two functions from a single button, this method will get rid of globalization and renaming and might be a bit better than the above mentioned solution:

```
def open():
    top = Toplevel()  # new window
    top.title("Kokomi")

    Label(top, text="This one automatically close when i click the next window").pack()
    Button(top, text="Close window", command=top.destroy).pack()
    Button(top, text="Next window", command=lambda: [top.destroy(),open2()]).pack()

def open2():
    top = Toplevel()  # new window
    top.title("Guide")

    Label(top, text="end").pack()
    Button(top, text="Close window", command=top.destroy).pack()  # destroy to quit things
```

Comment: Thank you thank you so much sir for the help and guide

Comment: @KurtLee If it solved your question, then make sure to mark as correct answer :)